# why is there space between controls if margin and padding are set to 0?

Tags: html, css

I have a div containing two input elements of type text and a label between them. It is for the user to define an interval (like 4 - 5). They display on the same line. All three controls have margin and padding set to 0. Firebug confirms that. Still there is some space between them. How come ? Where does this space come from ?

Comment: in anycase put at the top of your css the old school CSS Reset `*{ margin:0; padding:0 }` this will remove any extra margin or padding from everything. ;)

Comment: @aSeptik, still it does not apply to whitespace..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could very well be whitespace (*newlines / spaces*) between the elements.

see these examples to understand

```
<input type="text" /><label>-</label><input type="text" />
```

and

```
<input type="text" /> <label>-</label> <input type="text" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" />
<label>-</label>
<input type="text" />
```

will render differently.

**demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/rS2QQ/

Answer (score 1):

White space in your HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any whitespace between your inputs:

```
<input /> <input />
         ^
         |
         \_ space
```

Also, hyphen character always has some whitespace around it. You can specify negative letter-spacing in your CSS or add some negative margins.